# Parse XML-like file that has one extra field without tags

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I have the following file content:

```
<movie>
<title>Kung Fu Killer</title>
<genre>Martial arts</genre>
</movie>
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2952602/
```

I parse this file into a Java object with the following code:

```
  XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
  mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
  try {
      NfoFileXmlModel xmlFileContent = mapper.readValue(nfoFile.toFile(), NfoFileXmlModel.class);
  } catch (JsonParseException e) {
      log.debug("Failed to deserialize {} ({})", nfoFile, e.toString());
  }

@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
public class NfoFileXmlModel {
    @ToString
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class Art {
        String poster;
    }

    Art art;
    String year;
    String title;
}
```

This works well for the XML-like 'fields'.
How can I parse the last line, which is so to say 'anonymous', since there is no tags around the value?

Comment: This is not valid XML! You would have to parse the file "by hand" and extract the XML part  that you then read with the XML mapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the content of the file, wrap it with an extra root tag and read it as an `XML`. `XmlMapper` allows to handle problems using `DeserializationProblemHandler` class. There is a `handleUnknownProperty` method which you can override and handle your case. See below example:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializationProblemHandler;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;

public class XmlMapperApp {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        File xmlFile = new File("./resource/test.xml").getAbsoluteFile();
        String content = "<NfoRoot>" + String.join("", Files.readAllLines(xmlFile.toPath())) + "</NfoRoot>";

        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        xmlMapper.addHandler(new DeserializationProblemHandler() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext ctxt, JsonParser p, JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer, Object beanOrClass, String propertyName) throws IOException {
                if (beanOrClass instanceof NfoRoot) {
                    ((NfoRoot) beanOrClass).setRestOfTheFile(p.readValueAs(String.class));
                    return true;
                }

                return super.handleUnknownProperty(ctxt, p, deserializer, beanOrClass, propertyName);
            }
        });

        NfoRoot value = xmlMapper.readValue(content, NfoRoot.class);
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}

@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
class NfoFileXmlModel {
    @ToString
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class Art {
        String poster;
    }

    Art art;
    String year;
    String title;
    String genre;
}

@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
class NfoRoot {
    NfoFileXmlModel movie;

    String restOfTheFile;
}
```

Above code prints:

```
NfoRoot(movie=NfoFileXmlModel(art=null, year=null, title=Kung Fu Killer, genre=Martial arts), restOfTheFile=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2952602/)
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot! One tweak left, if the file contains *only* the url, the parser fails. Any possibility to handle this properly as well?

Comment: @kerner1000, you can check if file contains any `<` character which is not allowed in `URL`. If file contains it you can treat is an XML, in other case as a raw text. Also, you can use regular expression to check if content is `URL` - [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/161738/51591), if it does not match, just try to read parse it as `XML`

Answer (score 1):

Turn it into XML by adding a start and end tag:

```
<doc>
<movie>
<title>Kung Fu Killer</title>
<genre>Martial arts</genre>
</movie>
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2952602/
</doc>
```

and once it's been turned into XML, you can use all the XML technology you want.

Of course, this relies on the idea that if you add `<doc>` at the start and `</doc>` at the end, you will get well-formed XML. There's no way to be sure of that; if the last line were

```
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2952602/?x=3&y=4
```

then this approach would fail. It would be much better if you could persuade the originator of this data to use XML to start with - standards are useful!

Comment: That won't work, since this is a 'defined' format and other software expects files to be formatted like this.

Comment: If there's a specification then that helps enormously -- usually when people try to parse "XML-like" files the problem is that there is no spec, they're just trying to work it out from a few examples. But if there's a spec, you should point to it when asking the question, since the spec is fundamental to the answer. Of course, it would still be much better if they used XML, because there's lots of tooling readily available for XML.

Comment: @MichaelKay, `+1`, this is a right way to solve the problem, adding a root tag and parsing it as an `XML` this is what I did in my solution.